# React Native - Multiple countdown timers in one view with out re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer, react-native

I am building an app that has a screen in a stack navigator that renders multiple touchableOpacity's, all with an independent and unique countdown timer in seconds.

Each TouchableOpacity displays the remaining seconds in the count by subtracting the difference of the unique time and current time. 
The current time is stored as a state variable and when the component mounts, the function below is called.

```
    initTime() {
        setInterval( () => {
            this.setState({
                currentTime : new Date()
            })
          },1000)
    }
```

My issue is mainly performance, the view needs to re-render every second which causes older devices to really struggle with the constant rendering.

Is there any way I can achieve this without needing to re-render every second?

Comment: If you want the buttons to change their display text, something will need to re-render. However, depending on what else is being rendered, you may be able to increase performance by using `shouldComponentUpdate` or using memoize.

Comment: Did you get any better solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a count down component separately and import it anywhere. this component only updates himself and has not any issue on the parent view. I checked this method for about 100 components in one view and has not any problem.

Comment: I still have performance issues but have marked this correct as I believe there are other issues blocking the JS thread